How to get inherit size of bottomNavBar contents to dynamically size the bottom nav?
I want to size the BottomAppBar by affecting its height using the preferred and or inherited height of its contents (children).
I need to do this to decrease code duplication and potentially make it easy to maintain the code base later on. I have a wizard of about 9 steps and some of the buttons can vary, meaning that I need to manually assign a height value to the BottomAppBar widget if I want no overflow errors.
Current Documentation of the BottomNavBar widget in Flutter:
/// The double value is used to indicate the height of the [BottomAppBar].  
/// If this is null, the default value is the minimum in relation to the content,
/// unless [ThemeData.useMaterial3] is true, in which case it defaults to 80.0.
/// final double? height;


Due to material3, it uses a preferred size defined in material3, its about 80. Meaning that it defaults to that size if it's null or if no height is provided to the widget. Therefore, it cannot size dynamically as material 3 is restricting it from doing so.
Attempted Solutions:
They tried 3 options for sizing the widget dynamically, which as I now understand, cannot occur due to the restriction:

Usage of LayoutBuilder
Usage of IntrinsicHeight 
Usage of MediaQuery

Usage of LayoutBuilder:

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        TLoggerHelper.info(constraints.toString());
        return BottomAppBar(
          child: Container(
            color: Theme.of(context).bottomAppBarTheme.color,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: expand == true
                  ? CrossAxisAlignment.stretch
                  : centerContent == false
                      ? CrossAxisAlignment.start
                      : CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                /// App footer
                showMsaText == true
                    ? const Column(
                        children: [
                          TAppFooter(),
                          SizedBox(height: TSizes.spaceBtwItemsSm),
                        ],
                      )
                    : const SizedBox.shrink(),

                /// Bottom Nav content
                if (button != null)
                  button!
                else if (bottomNavBarContent != null)
                  bottomNavBarContent!(context)
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );

Constraint output: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=411.4, 0.0<=h<=914.3)
That constraint only has the max width and height of the physical screen rather than the space that the bottom app must occupy to render all of its children without overflow issues.
Usage of IntrinsicHeight:
As previously mentioned with the BottomAppBar itself, if no height is given, it results in a null height which defaults to the specified and standardized height of 80.
IntrinsicHeight should have worked as it precalculates the IntrinsicHeight of the children and assigns it to the container.
Usage of MediaQuery:
I pass in a height to the custom component using MediaQuery.of(context).size.height with a multiplier to provide dynamic sizing.
This works but again, it involves static values being assigned to the bottomNavBar. I don't know what the runtime height will be. I am only approximating it, literally eyeballing it.
Possible Solutions:
The only two other solutions I can think of are sticking with media query and assigning static heights dynamically calculated for the BottomNavBar.
Or, creating my custom widget that has a container, which should support the use of IntrinsicHeight.
If any of you have had the same issue, I would love to hear how you resolved it. What is a more elegant way of resolving this?
Thank you in advance :)

Maybe you could wrap the BottomAppBar in a Theme which has ThemeData containing useMaterial3: false although that might mess up the theming of the child then. Or maybe you could then also wrap the child of the BottomAppBar with another Theme with the original theme, although I'm not sure if that would work

widget for dynamic bottom navigation
class DynamicBottomAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final double defaultHeight;

  DynamicBottomAppBar({required this.child, this.defaultHeight = 80.0});

  @override
  Size get preferredSize {
    final childHeight = _calculateChildHeight();
    return Size.fromHeight(childHeight ?? defaultHeight);
  }

  double? _calculateChildHeight() {
    final renderBox = child.key != null
        ? (child.key as GlobalKey).currentContext?.findRenderObject() as RenderBox?
        : null;
    return renderBox?.size.height;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomAppBar(
      child: Container(
        color: Theme.of(context).bottomAppBarTheme.color,
        child: child,
      ),
    );
  }
}

that's how you can use
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return DynamicBottomAppBar(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        // Add your dynamic content here
        showMsaText ? const TAppFooter() : const SizedBox.shrink(),
        if (button != null) button! else if (bottomNavBarContent != null) bottomNavBarContent!(context),
      ],
    ),
  );
}


Thanks for the answer. I was able to resolve it. Will post the solution shortly. The solution that I determined still does not resolve the usage of BottomAppBar. I switched it for a container as I speculated in the question.

so you didn't tried this ?
